# Differentiability of a continuous (not absolutely continuous) CDF

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, derivatives

Similarly to Cantors Distribution define a Cumulative Distribution Function $F$ on $[0,1]$ as follows:

Let $\mu$ be the measure on $\{0,1,2\}$ with $\mu(\{0\})=2/5, \mu(\{1\})=1/5, \mu(\{2\})=2/5$. Let $\nu$ denote the product measure on $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$, which can be identified with a measure on $[0,1]$ via the 3-adic expansion. Let $F$ be the CDF of $\nu$.

Can you tell me anything about the differentiability of F?

I know that, as a monotone function, $F$ is almost everywhere differentiable, but can you say where exactly and with which values?

Edit:
For example, I am curious if $H(x)=\int_0^xF'(x)\not\equiv 0$ (unlike Cantors Distribution)